# Splitting ID column in pandas dataframe to multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like below :

```
    |  ID      |  Value |
    +----------+--------+
    |1C16      |  34    |
    |1C1       |  45    |
    |7P.75     |  23    |
    |7T1       |  34    |
    |1C10DG    |  34    |
    +----------+--------+
```

I want to split the ID column (its a string column) in a way that looks like below:

```
    |  ID      |  Value |  Code | Core |size |
    +----------+--------+-------+------+-----+
    |1C16      |  34    |   C   |  1   | 16  |
    |1C1       |  45    |   C   |  1   |  1  |
    |7P.75     |  23    |   P   |  7   | .75 |
    |7T1       |  34    |   T   |  7   | 1   |
    |1C10DG    |  34    |   C   |  1   | 10  |
    +----------+--------+-------+------+-----+
```

So how can this be achieved ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `.str.extract` with regex `(?P<Code>\d+)(?P<Core>[A-Z])(?P<size>[.0-9]+)` to capture the patterns:

```
df.ID.str.extract(r'(?P<Code>\d+)(?P<Core>[A-Z])(?P<size>[.0-9]+)')

#  Code Core size
#0    1    C   16
#1    1    C    1
#2    7    P  .75
#3    7    T    1
#4    1    C   10
```

Comment: wow wasn't aware you could place the column name into the regex expression, nice one

Comment: Psidom : Thanks for the answer, I also need the ID and value column in the result along with the split columns.

Comment: You can join the result with `df` to get the original columns `df.ID.str.extract(r'(?P<Code>\d+)(?P<Core>[A-Z])(?P<size>[.0-9]+)').join(df)`

Comment: You might have another column also named `Code` or `Core` or `size` ? You can try specify a different name in regex.

Comment: Psidom : Got it, as suggested had another column with same, which was causing the issue. One more - can we use merge instead of join here ?

Comment: You can merge on index which has the same effect as join.

Answer (score 2):

use `.str.extract()` with multiple capturing groups & `join`

```
df.join(
   df['ID'].str.extract('(\d)(\w)(\d+|.\d+)').rename(
           columns={0 : 'Core', 1 : 'Code', 2 : 'Size'}))

       ID  Value Core Code Size
1    1C16   34.0    1    C   16
2     1C1   45.0    1    C    1
3   7P.75   23.0    7    P  .75
4     7T1   34.0    7    T    1
5  1C10DG   34.0    1    C   10
```